# Google Maps HOC not receiving props

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, higher-order-components

I am trying to make this google maps HOC dynamic. I am passing the latitude and longitude through to the Component to replace the default position. This doesn't seem to be working. I am thinking that I need to pass in the props a different way. Any suggestions?

// Google Maps Component

```
import React from "react";
const { compose, withProps } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  TrafficLayer
} = require("react-google-maps");

const MapWithATrafficLayer = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${
      process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLEMAPS_API_KEY
    }&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={15}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }}
  >
    <TrafficLayer autoUpdate />
  </GoogleMap>
));

export default MapWithATrafficLayer;
```

// Component using Google Maps Component

```
<MyMapComponent
            lat={
              this.state.listingInfo.address.lat
            }
            lng={
              this.state.listingInfo.address.lng
            }
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the props your are passing to `GoogleMap` from `defaultCenter` to `center`. `defaultCenter` only works on the initial render, so if your state changes after that it will not reposition the map. You may need to use the `onCenterChanged` to update your state as the user moves around the map.